# How is the term "test run" typically used?

Tags: word-usage

Is the term "test run" used like the word "test" or is it more specific? I feel "test run" would be used in situations where products are being tested, but what about ideas, arguments?

> I did a few test runs of my debate arguments on a few audiences and
>   the reception was largely positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Test run*** can be used in the same way as *one* noun sense of ***test***, but it does have a more specific meaning.

The sense of test in question is that in "run some tests", as opposed to "I had a science test at school". But not every instance of *test* in that sense can be replaced.

A *test run* is a *run* of some process, or some equipment or whatever, for the purpose of *testing*. So you can have "test runs" of debate arguments - it means you run through the arguments in front of a test audience. It means using something to test it out.

So there is no "test run", as a noun phrase, if you go to hospital and they run tests on you. Those are tests *being* run on you.

So a speech might have a test run, a piece of software might have a test run. There's potential for confusing "running tests" with "having a test run". If you're familiar with the phrase *trial run*, that is broadly the same as *test run*.

In the case of software, you would "run tests" on software while it is being written, to make sure that individual components behave as intended, and then you would have "a test run" of the prototype once it is complete and you can try it out.

The only problem with the example you used is that it should be "a few test runs **of** my debate arguments".

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is slightly different, but I would rather say

> I did a few **tests** on my debate arguments on a few audiences and the reception was largely positive.

Or:

> I did a few **test runs of** my debate arguments on a few audiences and the reception was largely positive.